# How can I calculate column score in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I have 2 pandas data frame, one of them have a sentence split it by comma.

```
df2['lemmatized_nlp']
[el, bigdata, ser, uno, forma, que, guizhou, u...
[el, tipo, decir, porque, haber, mejor, luz, b...
[qué, ser, bigdata]
[a, el, variedad, volumen, y, veracidad, de,
```

...............

Another

```
lemma   v
abandonar   -0.200000
abarcativo  1.000000
abierto 0.800000
```

................

that have a word and the score for this word, (lemma, v). I need to score the first column data frame, looking for is the word appear on the second and calculate the score for the sentence
any ideas, how can I do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the following sample you could loop through the lists in the column, doing a lookup for the corresponding values in the other dataframe, then taking the sum of these values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[['qué', 'ser', 'bigdata']]], columns=['lemmatized_nlp'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'lemma':['qué', 'ser', 'bigdata'], 'v':[-0.2, 1, 0.8]})

df['score'] = df['lemmatized_nlp'].apply(lambda x: sum([df2['v'][df2['lemma'] == i].values[0] for i in x]))
```

result:

|  | lemmatized_nlp | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['qué', 'ser', 'bigdata'] | 1.6 |